# Access Dataframe's Row inside Row (nested JSON) with Pyspark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, row

Using pyspark, I am reading multiple files containing one JSON-object each from a folder *contentdata2*,

```
df = spark.read\
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")\
.json("./data/contentdata2/")

df.printSchema()
content = df.select('fields').collect()
```

where df.printSchema() yields

```
root
|-- fields: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- score: double (nullable = true)
|-- siteId: string (nullable = true)
```

**I wish to access fields.element.field, and store each field which equals body, and the field which equals urlhash (for each JSON object).**

The format of *content* is a Row (fields), containing other Rows, like this:

```
[Row(fields=[Row(field=‘body’, type=None, value=’[“First line of text“,”Second line of text”]), Row(field='urlhash', type=None, value='0a0b774c21c68325aa02cae517821e78687b2780')]),  Row(fields=[Row(field=‘body’, type=None, value=’[“First line of text“,”Second line of text”]), Row(field='urlhash', type=None, value='0a0b774c21c6caca977e7821e78687b2780')]), ...
```

The reason for the reappearing "[Row(field**s**=[Row(field=....) is because the JSON objects from the different files are being merged together in one list. There are also a lot of other Row elements as well which I am not interested in, and therefore did not include in the example.

The structure of the JSON objects looks like this:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "body",
      "value": [
        "Some text",
        "Another line of text",
        "Third line of text."
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "urlhash",
      "value": "0a0a341e189cf2c002cb83b2dc529fbc454f97cc"
    }
  ],
  "score": 0.87475455,
  "siteId": "9222270286501375973",
  "id": "0a0a341e189cf2c002cb83b2dc529fbc454f97cc"
}
```

I wish to store all words from the body of each url, to later remove stopwords and feed it into a K nearest neighbour algorithm.

How do I approach the problem of storing the words from the body for each url, preferably as a tsv or csv with columns urlhash and words (which is a list of words from body)?

Answer (score 14):

You can approach this in two ways:

- you can `explode` the `array` to get one record per line and then flatten the nested data frame
- or access the sub-fields directly (for Spark > 2.X)

Let's start with your sample data frame:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField('fields', ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('field', StringType()), 
        StructField('type', StringType()), 
        StructField('value', StringType())])))])

content = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([
        Row(
            fields=[
                Row(
                    field='body', 
                    type=None, 
                    value='["First line of text","Second line of text"]'), 
                Row(
                    field='urlhash', 
                    type=None, 
                    value='0a0b774c21c68325aa02cae517821e78687b2780')]), 
        Row(
            fields=[
                Row(
                    field='body', 
                    type=None, 
                    value='["First line of text","Second line of text"]'), 
                Row(
                    field='urlhash', 
                    type=None, 
                    value='0a0b774c21c6caca977e7821e78687b2780')])]), schema=schema)
content.printSchema()

    root
     |-- fields: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

**1. Explode and Flatten**

Nested data frames' fields can be access using `.`, `*` allows you to flatten all of the nested fields and bring them to the `root`level.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
content \
    .select(psf.explode('fields').alias('tmp')) \
    .select('tmp.*') \
    .show()

    +-------+----+--------------------+
    |  field|type|               value|
    +-------+----+--------------------+
    |   body|null|["First line of t...|
    |urlhash|null|0a0b774c21c68325a...|
    |   body|null|["First line of t...|
    |urlhash|null|0a0b774c21c6caca9...|
    +-------+----+--------------------+

    root
     |-- field: string (nullable = true)
     |-- type: string (nullable = true)
     |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

**2. access sub-fields directly**

In later version of Spark you can access fields of nested `StructType`s even when they are contained in an `ArrayType`. You'll end up with an `ArrayType` of the sub-field's values.

```py
content \
    .select('fields.field') \
    .show()

    +---------------+
    |          field|
    +---------------+
    |[body, urlhash]|
    |[body, urlhash]|
    +---------------+

    root
     |-- field: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: omg, thank you. I have spent a day dividing sub-columns of my file. You saved my day.